# fread returns zero

Tags: c, file, file-io

I have a function that reads a rom file into memory and automatically allocates to fit the file but every time I try to read from the file descriptor, fread() returns zero. I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong. can anybody help?

```
int read_rom(const char *filename, unsigned char ***rom) {
    int rom_size;
    FILE *fd = NULL;

    if((fd = fopen(filename, "r")) != NULL) {
        fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
        rom_size = ftell(fd);
        (*rom) = malloc(rom_size);
        int read = fread(rom, 1, rom_size, fd);
        fclose(fd);

        printf("read: %d\n", read);

        return rom_size;
    }

    return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    unsigned char rom_size = 0;
    unsigned char **rom = NULL;
    rom_size = read_rom(argv[1], &rom);

    return 1;
}
```

Any takers?

Comment: When `fread` returns zero, you can use `feof` and `ferror` to investigate whay.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You aren't reading anything in because you `fseek`ed to the end of the file.  Do a `fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);` to return to the beginning of the file before you `fread`.

Comment: Or rewind() if you prefer - note the missing 'f'

Comment: oh jees, I forgot to rewind() ... I must be blind.

thanks a lot for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

If fread returns zero, then **either of** End-of-file *or* an Error occurred.

> RETURN VALUE
>
> fread()  and  fwrite()  return the number of items successfully read
>   or
>          written (i.e., not the number of characters).  If an error  occurs, 
>   or
>          the  end-of-file is reached, the return value is a short item count
>   (or
>          zero).
>
> fread() does not distinguish between end-of-file and error, and
>   callers
>          must use feof(3) and ferror(3) to determine which occurred.

I suggest you should check for errors on the file, and if an error occurred, you should print the relevant error message to get more information! This should be part of both your current debugging but also of the finished code as error handling.